# How to sort HashMap<String,ArrayList> in Android?

Tags: android, collections

How to sort `HashMap<String,ArrrayList<String>>`?

I am fetching contact name from phone contacts like:

```
"String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));"
```

And stored it into one `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>`. But all contacts I am getting in unsorted order.

May I know how to sort those contacts in alphabetical order so that I can display list view in sorted order?

Comment: did you search this topic before posting the question?

Comment: i searched but i got only how to parse HashMap<string,string> or  HashMap<string,int>

Comment: since two days i am stucking on this

Comment: HashMap<String,ArrayList>. ArrayList of what? More strings?

Comment: Just use Comparator for that....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code to get Contacts in Ascending Order of String names as follows:

```
public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {


        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        } 


        phones.close();
    }
```

[Code for reference](https://github.com/cycorax12/FollowUp/blob/master/SMS4U/src/in/cycorax/activities/DisplayContactsActivity.java)

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: one more question .can you tell me how to add search option in my custom adapter for listview

Comment: @User_B You can add a EditText component as HeaderView in ListView of yours.

Comment: do you have some snippet

Comment: Just put Edit Text above listview component else

Comment: @User_B you are looking for this i guess http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: yes i rhave already refferd this link but result is like when i type 'a' ,all the names which conatins 'a' for eg. 'manish' is also displayed. how to dispay records only starting with whatever i typed in edit text

Comment: you need to implement something like trie data structure then.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your data from the database already sorted. Just use

```
String orderBy =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " DESC";
```

in your query. After that, usually when you need to use HashMap an have also sorted data, then you use `HashMap` + `ArrayList`. In HashMap you keep normal key,value pairs, in `ArrayList` you keep sorted values (in case if you have already sorted data, you add it to `ArrayList` while reading, you don't need to sort again).

If you need to sort ArrayList which is value in your HashMap, you can use:

```
Collections.sort(yourArrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below class and pass List of data to the it. It will give you new sorted list.

```
public class CompareApp implements Comparator<AppDetails> {

private List<AppDetails> apps = new ArrayList<AppDetails>();

Context context;

public CompareApp(String str,List<AppDetails> apps, Context context) {
    this.apps = apps;
    this.context = context;

    Collections.sort(this.apps, this);
}

@Override
public int compare(AppDetails lhs, AppDetails rhs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return lhs.label.toUpperCase().compareTo(rhs.label.toUpperCase());
}
```

}

Comment: AppDetails is a generic class

Comment: public class AppDetails {
 public String label;
 public String packageName;
 public Drawable icon;
}